# Problem with a select converting to a List ASP.Net Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code

```
public async Task<JsonResult?> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Users == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var user = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    var securities = _context.UsersSecurities.Where(x => x.UserId == id).ToList();

    //var expected = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { user = Json(user), securities = Json(securities) }));
    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return Json(user);
}
```

In that function i receive an id an with that find an user by it primarykey UserID, and then search into the UsersSecurities model to search rows with that UserID (It is a relationship inside the database), well... i return a Json to the Ajax function that calls it... watch teh debugger view:
[image: Yes] 
The user loads well

---

Now watch the usersecurities variable

[image]

The variable loads well and transform it into a list, all good until here but and i only return the user variable with Json() transform but in the JavaScript appear this error:

[image]

That error started when i append the Select of the UserSecurities, and when a user don't have any UserSecurities record it works well, i don't know what it's happening with that, it is just... strange, somebody help me please, i just wanna convert the user with their usersecurities into a json to return it

Comment: Feel free to ask me for any additional information please, i really need to solve this but i don't have idea what it's happening, the program doesn't throw any exception o message

Comment: Can you please share your `Startup.cs` configuration with `services.AddMvc` or `services.AddControllers` or `services.AddControllersWithViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `User` image, it has `Securities` loaded. If you expand those `Securities` you will find `User` object and so on. Thus it is going to be infinite `Reference loop`.

You can fix this behavior in your response with below configuration. You can append `AddNewtonsoftJson` configuration to `services.AddMvc` or `services.AddControllers` or `services.AddControllersWithViews`

```
// Append AddNewtonsoftJson with AddMvc or AddControllers or AddControllersWithViews, based on what you have used.
// services.AddMvc()
// services.AddControllersWithViews()
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```